# How to draw an n sample from U(a,b) of numbers not close?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I need to draw an n sample from the uniform distribution on the interval [a,b] such that no two numbers are closer than d > 0. I can draw a sample and check this property and then throw it away and try again if not, but if n is large relative to b-a that could take a looong time. Is there a simple and nice algorithm to solve this problem? The numbers got to be uniformly distributed on [a,b], no deterministic setup.

Comment: Here's a thought. The distance from one point to the next greater in a sample from U(0, 1) has some well-known distribution -- I forget what it is, but it's something like 1/x, I'm sure you can look it up. Sample from that distribution, but exclude any samples less than d. It's not guaranteed that the resulting sequence is between 0 and b - a, so I guess you'll also have to throw out any that make the sum too big.

Comment: FWIW this question is off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to choosing n numbers greater than or equal to d and whose sum is equal to b - a.

There will be some solution provided that n * d <= b - a. We can write a recursive algorithm that looks for one:

b - a - X < (n - 1) * D
X > b - a - (n - 1) * d

```
FindSpacedSample(n, d, a, b)
1. if n * d > b - a then return "no solution"
2. avail = [d, b - a - (n - 1) * d]
3. guess = random(avail)
4. print(guess)
5. FindSpacedSample(n - 1, d, a + guess, b)
```

Example: n = 5, a = 0, b = 10, d = 1, assuming real numbers

```
FindSpacedSample(5, 1, 0, 10)
5 * 1 >? b - a? no
avail = [1, 10 - 0 - 4 * 1] = [1, 6]
guess = random(avail) = 2 (for the sake of argument)
print(2)

FindSpacedSample(4, 1, 2, 10)
4 * 1 >? 10 - 2? no
avail = [1, 10 - 2 - 3 * 1] = [1, 5]
guess = random(avail) = 4 (for the sake of argument)
print(4)

FindSpacedSample(3, 1, 6, 10)
3 * 1 >? 10 - 6? no
avail = [1, 10 - 6 - 2 * 1] = [1, 2]
guess = random(avail) = 1 (for the sake of argument)
print(1)

FindSpacedSample(2, 1, 7, 10)
2 * 1 >? 10 - 7? no
avail = [1, 10 - 7 - 1 * 1] = [1, 2]
guess = random(avail) = 2 (for the sake of argument)
print(2)

FindSpacedSample(1, 1, 9, 10)
1 * 1 >? 10 - 9? no
avail = [1, 10 - 9 - 0 * 1] = [1, 1]
guess = 1
print(1)
```

We should also have stopping condition n = 0. Then we get the sequence of spaces 2, 4, 1, 2, 1; we see these sum to ten; and we can get the values as follows:

```
point1 = 2                  = 2
point2 = 2 + 4              = 6
point3 = 2 + 4 + 1          = 7
point4 = 2 + 4 + 1 + 2      = 9
point5 = 2 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 1  = 10
```

Now, there are a couple of ways in which this result is less than totally uniform:

1. the first number will never be less than d
2. earlier numbers tend to be spaced further apart

We can fix these by:

1. shuffling the spacings before converting to points
2. subtracting from each point some random value from [0, point1 - a].

So, if we shuffled 2, 4, 1, 2, 1 to 4, 1, 1, 2, 2 we'd get points 4, 5, 6, 8, 10; and if we subtracted 3 from each one (taken randomly between 0 and 4) we'd get 1, 2, 3, 5, 7.

Does this give you a uniform distribution over the set of all possible solutions? I'd be surprised if it did, but I'd also be surprised if what this does give you differs from that truly uniform distribution to an appreciable degree.

Comment: Interesting :). But you are generating the order statistics, not the variables themselves. There is no first var, second var etc in your setup. How would you amend that? Another question:  Why do earlier numbers tend to be spaced further apart? The problem that the first order var is never less than d can be amended by working with the interval [a-d, b]. Shuffling seems all right, but do you really need it?

Comment: The length of the interval from which you draw the next step is b - a - nd . As n goes down this goes up! So the steps are not identically distributed. Problem.

Comment: @Henrik4 On your second comment - note that a is increasing with each recursive call, which counteracts the nd term to some degree. On your first one - to go from spacings to points you'd add them cumulatively as I illustrate. The analysis of the uniformity of the resulting distribution is probably a little too hard to attempt here, but it might be possible to empirically test this method to see whether the distribution of results is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Aha, when you have generated the steps s1,...,sm the interval for s(m+1) becomes [d, b - a - sum(si) - (n-m-1)*d], is that right? A problem is that this interval is stochastic so all the steps are differently distributed. You misunderstand me about the order statistics: You generate the ordered vars: x1 < x2 < ...  There is no first var, second var and so on like if you generated them in time. I want vars x1,...,xn which are all uniformly distributed on [a,b] and not necessarily x1 < x2 etc.

Comment: @Henrik4 You're right about it being stochastic... like I said, I doubt it's perfectly uniform over the space of all possible solutions, but my gut says it will look pretty good (what solution is more likely than another using this method?) If you don't want point1 < point2 … then shuffle the points after constructing them from the spacings.

Comment: What solution more likely? The early steps have greater freedom than the later. The first step can be almost anything, but if the previous steps are large the last one is strictly bounded.